# Could I avoid retyping two very similar functions using scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

My sample is as simple as this:

```
def func(arg1: Long, arg2: Long, arg3: String) {
  privateFunc1(arg1);
  privateFunc2(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

and this is an overloaded function which also works

```
def func(arg1: Long, arg2: Long, arg3: File) {
  privateFunc1(arg1);
  privateFunc2(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

as you might have guessed the privateFunc2 is already overloaded that is why both functions work.

Could I avoid this redundant repetition of code that in scala by using function composition perhaps?
What would be the best practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the overloading is confusing things a bit. The re-use of the same name makes it look like the code is similar, but `func` is calling a different method in each case, so you might as well call the private methods different things.

If the two versions of `privateFunc2` really are similar, is a conversion / pre-processing that can be done, say from `File` to `String` or vice versa, or to convert both to a collection? You then just have 1 version of `privateFunc2`, and one of the versions of `func` applies the conversion and forwards it to the other, and you've eliminated the redundancy in having 2 versions.

I would stay away from `Either` and implicit conversions, since if you want to do it properly you need to use a wrapper type (implicit conversions between common types is strongly discouraged since it can cause problems elsewhere in your code) and in any case you're just delaying the inevitable branching to deal with each possiblilty, as well as introducing a bunch of boilerplate.

tl;dr: split up `privateFunc2` so it only takes 1 input type. Or keep it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could try using an `Either[String,File]` for the 3rd arg.  You would then have to do matching in `privateFunc2`.  Code could look like this:

```
def func(arg1: Long, arg2: Long, arg3: Either[String,File]) {
  privateFunc1(arg1);
  privateFunc2(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

def privateFunc2(arg1: Long, arg2: Long, arg3: Either[String,File]){
  arg3 match{
    case Left(str) => //handle string case
    case Right(file) => //handle file case
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

In all honesty though, if the `String` is really a path to a `File`, then setup the private func to only work with the `File` input and then overload the public func to take both `String` and `File` as the 3rd arg and then in the one that takes a `String`, convert to a `File` and call the private func.  This works as well and keeps things relatively simple.

Comment: Lets introduce wrapper and implicit conversions to save two lines. That's *good*.

Comment: @om-nom-nom, can you elaborate a bit more so I can modify the answer?

Comment: sadly I don't have anything better than your proposition :-( so all I can do is to complain about overengineering

Comment: @om-nom-nom ya, personally, I would not include the implicits and that's why I don't have them in my main answer block.  I only added them to show what one could do if they had distaste for having to explicit set the type of the `Either`

Comment: Thank you! I am new to functional programming and I thought I might be missing something. But yep sure `Either` can do the job on this particular case

Comment: So you've increased line-count, increased # of methods from 2 to 4 (including 2 implicits, which introduces non-obvious magic into your solution), increased complexity, decreased readability, increased objects created (optimizer likely won't filter these out!), increased runtime, ...  seriously?

Comment: @RichardSitze, as I mentioned in my post to om-nom-nom, I would not use implicits either, I just put them there to show how one might be able to deal with the distaste for explicitly wrapping the inputs into `Left` or `Right`.  I have since removed the code about implicits though and left the `Either` solution as is while also offering another simpler solution.  You can douse the torches and call off the mob ;)